# How to access workspace created in azure portal?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I created workspace in azure.  I can't see that workspace in app.Powerbi.com nor power bi desktop.  How do I access the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You should log in to https://portal.azure.com , then either search for your workspace name, or browse under More Services / Intelligence + Analytics / Power BI workspace collections.

Comment: I can see the workspace Id in azure portal, but I want to access in app.Powerbi.com and power bi desktop

Comment: PBI Embedded is not exposed in app.powerbi.com.  It's up to you to build the report in Power BI Desktop and publish it to PBIE.

Comment: I suspect you need to slow down and read up on the architecture a bit more. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-what-is-power-bi-embedded